# What title to put in CV if you do research but unfunded?

Tags: cv

As the title suggested, if you have been doing research consistently with a professor, can you write RA as your title in CV? If not, what should be the title to put there instead to show that you have done research in that lab? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you _need_ a job title? Just list the positions you previously had, probably stating the last one with "independent researcher".

Answer (score 2):

If you are a student at a university it's probably unwise to claim to have a title there if you don't have it. Simply putting 'student' is probably better. On the other hand, many departments have unpaid, "zero hour" appointments if you really want an official title.

If you're not at a university and you fund yourself I suppose you can technically give yourself whatever title you want, but "independent researcher" would seem like a fitting description.

Answer (score 0):

The different faculty has different views on this, one of them said to me once that "Project Assistant" or "Research Assistant" means full-time researcher and unsuitable for this case, but others don't mind. Same with Undergraduate or Graduate Researcher.

Rather than the title, the explanation of your role and accomplishments in this research should be concisely written in one-two sentences, this is much more significant.